# Dynamic sequence/Ordering of tabs (Notebook/Page tag) in odoo 13

Tags: odoo-13

My problem is the dynamic ordering of tabs in odoo.

I have a sequence field in process.sheet. In my example below NDT is 1 and Quality in is 2.

[image]

is this possible that the ordering of tabs will start at NDT next is Quality in.
[image]

Same also if kit tab/page is 1 it will go first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing in odoo. But as a work a round you can hide the tabs and show them by a selection field if you want your view to become more readable and less messy.

**your_model.py**

```
show_page = fields.Selection([
    ('quality', 'Quality'),
    ('ndt', 'NDT'),
    ('other', 'Other'),
], required=True)
```

**your_view.xml**

```
<form>
    <sheet>
        <group>
            <field name="show_page"/>
        </group>
        <notebook>
            <page string="Quality" attrs="{'invisible':[('show_page','!=','quality')]}">

            </page>
            <page string="NDT" attrs="{'invisible':[('show_page','!=','quality')]}">

            </page>
            <page string="Others" attrs="{'invisible':[('show_page','!=','other')]}">

            </page>
        </notebook>
    </sheet>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah I already did this but they want is the sequence of tabs are dynamic anw thanks.